# Show Admin notice only on plugin update

Tags: wordpress

I need to perform a database upgrade on my plugin update. This upgrade shouldn't be done on plugin activation. Only for plugin update. But i am not able to do so. I tried `upgrader_process_complete`, but that didn't work since it was old version that run before updating.

I plan to add a transient on plugin updation and check on page load for transient and perform database upgrade. But i don't find any hook to set transient on plugin updation. Please correct me or help me to find the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do is to save a version to db and check if the current version and stored version is different. Then perform the action needed.